# Python Tkinter: ¿Como ajusto la imagen al tamaño del boton?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa y es la primera vez que necesito usar imagenes en botones, segui un tutorial usando el paquete `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` e hice un boton de prueba con la foto de una calculadora, pero pasa que si por ejemplo, pongo el `width` y el `height` a 100 por ejemplo, la imagen no se estira ni se adapta al tamaño del boton

Codigo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTK

btn_calculator = Image.open('DIRECCION DEL ARCH.')
window.btn_calculator = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_calculator)

calculator = Button(window, image=window.btn_calculator, width=100, height=100)
calculator.pack()
calculator.place(x=80, y=60)
```

La foto es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La dimension de la foto es de 225x255

Entonces ¿Como hago para que la imagen se adapte al tamaño del boton? ¿Tengo que cambiar las dimensiones de la foto para que encaje? Y si es asi ¿Hay alguna forma mas facil?

Saludos.

Comment: La respuesta es sí hasta donde yo se, tienes que cambiar el tamaño de la imagen. Lo puedes hacer modificando el archivo con un editor de imagen (recomendado) o usando el método [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) del objeto Image de Pillow

Comment: Puedes darme un ejemplo usando ese metodo? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sí hasta donde yo se, tienes que cambiar el tamaño de la imagen. Lo puedes hacer modificando el archivo con un editor de imagen (recomendado) o usando el método [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) del objeto Image de Pillow.

Por lo que vi, preferiste que cada vez que se carge tu programa, la imagen se adapte. Por lo que profundizaré más en el método resize.

resize es un método en los objetos Image del modulo Pillow (el que usas para cargar la imagen) que nos permite darle un nuevo tamaño a la imagen.
Este método devuelve una copia de la imagen original pero con otro tamaño. También puedes personalizar el filtro de resampling. Hay otras opciones, pero en mi opinión no son relevantes para la pregunta.

El primer argumento es una tupla del estilo (nuevo ancho, nueva altura). El segundo argumento es el filtro de resampling que se usará para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen. Para saber que filtro se usará por default puedes leer esta [seccion de la documentación](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize):

> If the image has mode “1” or “P”, it is always set to
> PIL.Image.NEAREST. If the image mode specifies a number of bits, such
> as “I;16”, then the default filter is PIL.Image.NEAREST. Otherwise,
> the default filter is PIL.Image.BICUBIC.

En tu caso, tu código debería de quedar así:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTK

btn_calculator = Image.open('DIRECCION DEL ARCH.')
# Cambio el tamaño de la imagen a (100, 100) con el filtro default.
# Luego guardo la nueva imagen en btn_calculator (recuerda que resize NO modifica la imagen original, por lo que debemos reemplazar la imagen original por la nueva)
btn_calculator = btn_calculator.resize((100, 100))
window.btn_calculator = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_calculator)

calculator = Button(window, image=window.btn_calculator, width=100, height=100)
calculator.pack()
calculator.place(x=80, y=60)
```

Es importante que esta linea `btn_calculator = btn_calculator.resize((100, 100))` esté antes de esta `window.btn_calculator = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_calculator)`. Es decir, antes de crear el objeto PhotoImage. De lo contrario, no ocurrirá ningún cambio a la imagen.